# How to match lines that ONLY have repeated pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a (compound) word with 2 or more internal dot characters (not periods)

1. this line has single•dotted word
2. this line•has two•dots but in two words
3. while this line has several•dots•that are inside a word
4. also would like to match a•line•like•this with more than 1 dot
5. and would•like•to match a line•that has single and multiple dotted lines

Lines 3-5 are a match

So far I can match *all* of these like this:

> \w•\w

but I can't figure out how to *exclude* lines like 1 and 2.

*This is a simplified version of my actual problem, which is searching for a particular pattern within Xcode. I figure I need to improve my knowledge of regex in general*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex only looks for one dot. Try

```
\w•\w+•
```

The `+` allows one or more repetitions of the previous token, so this regex would match `l•dots•` in line 3.

Answer (score 1):

`(\w+•\w+•(?:\w+•)*\w+)`
this will help you to catch matches from your strings

so, let's play with it:
`\w+`<- this match word
`\w+•\w+•` <- this catch words with two dots, like this: `a•line•`
`(?:\w+•)*` <- this match next `[0,infinity]` times of `\w+•`  like this: `a•line•like•`<- it will catch `a•`, `line•`, `like•`(and other words with one dot after word OR it catch zero length string)
`(?:pattern)`<- i use this to prevent match behavior, it is only grouping.
`\w+` <- it will catch last word

so, let's see at pattern now:

`(word•word•([grouping]word•)[0, infinity]{times}word)`

`word•word•word` will catching
`word•word•word•word` will catching
`word•word•word•word•word` will catching

and so on

it will catch sequence of words, that separated with only one dot and which have [3,infinity] words in it.